# How to make JTable show refreshed data after updating database?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh

I have updated a database and I would like to refresh a `JTable` with this code tied to a button click event, but it doesn't work. When I close aplication and open it again `JTable` shows the right data.

Do I need to override some method on my abstract table?

```
try {
        model=new MyTableModel(this.database);
        table = new JTable(model);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ((MyTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();

    }
});

 class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private int i;
    private String[] columnNames = { "ID", "Code", "Country", "Radio",
            "primljeno", "select" };

    private Object[][] data = { { new Integer(0), "", "", "", "",
            new Boolean(false) } };

    public MyTableModel(My_class_Database database)throws SQLException {
            init(database);


    }
    public void init(My_class_Database database) throws SQLException
    {
        this.i = database.checkIsDataThere();
        Object[][] object;
        if (i == 0) {
            object = new Object[i][7];
            object = database.getDatafromDatabase(this.i);
            this.data = object;
            dataAp = object;

        } else {
            object = database.getDatafromDatabase(this.i);
            textField.setText("No data in database");
        }

    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];

    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {

        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

    }

    // problem sa null vrijednostima,null exception
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col > 4) {
            return true;
        } else
            return (false);
    }

}
```

Comment: One way is to read all the data from the database and create a new TableModel. Then you can use JTable.setModel() method.

Comment: Hard to tell without code. Please post back an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and let us know.

Comment: added my_model implementation

Answer (score 1):

As it is (posted code) the model is not aware of the modification in the database. You could either refresh the data in the model, such as calling existing `init()` method or creating a similar one. As an alternative, you can build a new model and reset it on the table.

It is the responsibility of the model to fire notifications such as `fireTableDataChanged` that you use in `actionPerformed`. Table clients should not execute these methods.  `fireTableDataChanged` belongs to `init()` method for example. See [Firing Data Change Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) for more details and examples.

The model should be about data, so it is best if you move the logic of setting `textField` out of the model. If needed you can expose additional methods from the model to help clients get additional details about data and state.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many things but finally this worked for me:

```
if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
         for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
             model.removeRow(i);
         }
     }

     setTablevalue();
```

I removed all the rows from the JTable and again called the setTableValue method to re-populate the table.