# Refresh JTable firetableDataChanged is not executed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I try to update my JTable with the fireTableChanged() Method after i imported the names of spreadsheets from excel in my datastructure but the Method is not executed. I confirmed with a test that the data is correctly imported and that the jtable should have the necessary informationen.

What do i have to do that the JTable is correctly updated?
I found several other links to this topic but none of them worked for me:

[Refresh Jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491005/refresh-jtable)

[How to make JTable show refreshed data after updating database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076301/how-to-make-jtable-show-refreshed-data-after-updating-database)

[JTable How to refresh table model after insert delete or update the data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data)

[AbstractDataTable fireTableDataChanged() does not refresh jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163156/abstractdatatable-firetabledatachanged-does-not-refresh-jtable)

[Can't refresh my JTable with new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093053/cant-refresh-my-jtable-with-new-data)

Model:

```
public class Model extends Observable {
String[][] data;
List<Arbeitsmappe> AMList = new LinkedList<>();
.....
public void setAMList(List<Arbeitsmappe> aMList) {
AMList = aMList; //new List replace the old
this.getData(); //The 2dimensional Array is filled with the names from the list
setChanged(); 
notifyObservers(Controller.Command_Excel_Eingelesen);
 }
}
```

View:

```
    JTextField cellEditorTF = new JTextField();
    cellEditorTF.setEditable(false);
    DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(cellEditorTF);

    ContentTable = new JTable(model.getData(), Model.columnNames);
    //Cell Editable FALSE
    ContentTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(cellEditor);
    //Single Interval Selection 
    ContentTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    //Cell Listener - When Cell is edited the new informationen is safed in AMLISt
    Action action = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
            Model.AMList.get(tcl.getRow()).Speichername = String.valueOf(tcl.getNewValue());
           // System.out.println("Row: " + tcl.getRow() + "  " + Model.data[tcl.getRow()][1]);
        }
    };
    TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(ContentTable, action);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(ContentTable);
    ContentTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    ContentTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    this.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,ButtonPanel);
    this.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,scrollPane);

}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    if(arg0 instanceof Model){
        Model model = (Model) arg0;
        String cmd = (String) arg1;
        if(cmd.equals(Controller.Command_Excel_Eingelesen)){

            ((AbstractTableModel)ContentTable.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
            ContentTable.repaint();
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Note also that you shouldn't be calling any `fireXxxx()` methods on your table model. These should only be called internally within your table model itself. Your design appears broken by your doing this.

Answer (score 4):

1. `((AbstractTableModel)ContentTable.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();` is called out of models definitions, it should't be, must be part of code, class void that override `AbstractTableModel` and its methods
2. as aside this method reseting all custom properties for model, and important part of methods for `JTable` (e.g. override for `XxxTableCellRenderer`/`Editor`)
3. [read API in part methods for fireTableXxxXxx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), there are notifiers for all `JTable`/`AbstractTableModel`'s lifecycle, be sure that youare used the correct notifier for every actions/event